# probability of rolling combined $3$ or lower with $4$ dice, discarding the highest $2$ using combination math?

Tags: combinatorics, dice

Using Python script to simulate, I found that if you roll $4$ dice, discarding the highest two results and the resulting sum being $3$ or lower has a probability of $\sim 0.3285$.

How does one calculate this without simulating a large number of dice rolls?
Edit, here is the python code used for the approximation simulation:

```
from random import randint

def dice_roll(amount):
    r = []
    for i in range(amount):
        r.append(randint(1,6))
    r.sort()
    return r
    
count = 0
it = 10000
amount_of_dice = 4
max_sum_of_lowest_two = 3

for i in range(it):
    if sum(dice_roll(amount_of_dice)[:2]) <= max_sum_of_lowest_two:
        count += 1
print(count/it)
```

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The more you put in restrictions like "discarding highest two rolls" and such the more tedious and complicated a problem like this gets.  In my opinion, the easiest way would be to use computer assistance to actually run through all $6^4$ possibilities and count how many satisfy your condition.  That's only $1296$ possibilities and so should complete almost instantly.  I would not suggest trying to do this with a pen-and-paper approach.  In doing so, you will get an exact result and not just a simulated result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on a pen-and-paper result, you can break into cases:  At least two 1's rolled (*and so sum of 2*), and Exactly one 1 rolled with at least one 2 rolled.  For the first case, you could calculate as $1$ minus the probability of exactly zero or exactly one 1 rolled.  For the second case, it is the probability of exactly one 1 minus the probability of exactly one 1 with no 2's.

$$\underbrace{\left(1 - \overbrace{\frac{5^4}{6^4}}^{\text{no 1's}} - \overbrace{4\cdot\frac{5^3}{6^4}}^{\text{one 1}}\right)}_{\text{at least two 1's}} + \underbrace{\left(\overbrace{4\cdot\frac{5^3}{6^4}}^{\text{one 1}}-\overbrace{4\cdot\frac{4^3}{6^4}}^{\text{one 1, no 2's}}\right)}_{\text{one 1 and at least one 2}} = \frac{415}{1296}$$

To emphasize, I would *not* recommend doing this if the numbers were even slightly different.  I would not recommend doing this for sum of $4$ or less, nor would I recommend doing this for the general problem.

---

example of code to brute force the calculation:

`tot=0; count=0; for(a=1;a<7; a++){ for(b=1; b<7; b++){ for(c=1; c<7; c++){ for(d=1; d<7; d++){tot=tot+1; if (a+b<4 || a+c<4 || a+d<4 || b+c<4 || b+d<4|| c+d<4){ count=count+1}}}}}`

The above gives that `count` is equal to $415$ and `total` gives $1296$ as expected.  Adjusting the pen-and-paper approach to accommodate the sum being $4$ or less instead would be tedious.  Adjusting the code above replacing 4's with 5's gives the probability of the sum being $4$ or less as $\dfrac{676}{1296}$ very easily.  Given time and effort, one could write the code in such a way as to have a variable number of dice, a variable number of discards, a variable number of sides, and a variable target.  I leave that as an exercise to the reader if desired.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the explanation, to elaborate a bit, I play a tabletop game where these kind of exceptions often are the case, and I was looking for a generic approach to calculate this, but it seems to be the case that this is not an option.

Comment: For what it's worth, your simulation of "~0.537" is dubious.  I would check your work there.

Comment: You are right, I left out the exception where u get to reroll the dice if you don't succeed for simplicity but didn't change that result. fixed the post

Comment: I also added the software I used to approximate the value. I think time complexity of this problem is $O^n$ with $n$ for the amount of dice, brute force has its limits